# cursor issues , pointer changes it shape while hovering into split window

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, graphics, intel-graphics

experiencing cursor issues specifically when hovering over different windows in a split-screen setup, and the cursor icon changes(like pointer, blinker, and other icon) momentarily before returning to the original icon,

tried following things but haven't resolve the problem

reinstall tweaks,
upadate softerware,
change the curssor themes and soft brightness enable and disable , tried all things
also take the help of chatGPT

that kind of iretating, if you guys know the sol , please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.